# Solve Cauchy Integral using residues

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I have an exam tomorrow, and we were given like an "example test" without answers, and one question is to solve this Cauchy integral:

$$
\oint_c = \frac {2z+1} {(z+1)^2(z-3)} 
$$

with circle $ c: |z-2|=5 $

the function has a double pole in $ -1 $ and a single pole in $ 3 $, both of the poles being inside of the circle.

Residue $ f(3) $:
$$
\lim_{z \rightarrow 3}(\frac{2z+1}{(z+1)^2}) = \frac 7 {16}
$$

Residue $ f(-1) $:
$$
\frac {1} {1!} \lim_{z \rightarrow -1}(\frac{2z+1}{z-3})' = \lim_{z \rightarrow -1}(\frac{2(z-3)-(2z+1)}{(z-3)^2}) = \frac {2(-4) - (-1)} {(-4)^2} = \frac {-7}{16}
$$

that makes the final result be:
$$
2 \pi i (\frac {7}{16} + \frac {-7}{16}) = 0
$$

Am I correct? For some reason, I find it odd, that the answer would be a 0 on an exam, but I can't check it anywhere, and I don't seem to see a mistake in my math.

Comment: It follows from ${2z+1 \over (z+1)^2 (z-3)} = -{7 \over 16} {1 \over z+1} + {1 \over 4} {1 \over (z+1)^2}+ {7 \over 16} {1 \over z-3}$.

Comment: +1 Yes, it's correct. Good luck with your test tomorrow o(*￣︶￣*)o

Answer (score 2):

It's correct.  Here is a generalisation which explains why this is not a coincidence.

**Theorem**.  Let $p(z)$ and $q(z)$ be polynomials with ${\rm degree}(q)\ge {\rm degree}(p)+2$.  Let $C$ be a circle with centre $0$ which has all the zeros of $q(z)$ inside it.  Then
$$\int_C \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}\,dz=0\ .$$

**Sketch of proof**.  Let $C$ be such a circle.  Since $C$ includes all the singularities of $p(z)/q(z)$, increasing the radius will not change the value of the integral: hence,
$$\int_C \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}\,dz
  =\lim_{r\to\infty}\int_{|z|=r} \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}\,dz\ .$$
But estimating the right-hand side gives
$$\left|\,\int_{|z|=r} \frac{p(z)}{q(z)}\,dz\,\right|
  \le (2\pi r)\frac{c_1r^{{\rm deg}\,p}}{c_2r^{{\rm deg}\,q}}\to0\ \ \hbox{as $r\to\infty$}\ .$$

**Comment**.  It should now be clear that $C$ doesn't need to have centre $0$, in fact, doesn't even need to be a circle, just any simple closed curve which has all the zeros of $q(z)$ inside it.